# Problema al conectar a CloudMqtt con variables

Tags: javascript, html

Amigos tengo el siguiente código en html, en donde me conecto a CloudMqtt, el problema radica es que estoy pasando el usuario, la contraseña, el puerto y el host a traves del codigo. Estoy tratando de hacer un formulario para que el usuario ingrese dichos datos pero no consigo que funcione, he intentado hacerlo mediante document.getElementsByName o por Id, pero no funciona, no se que pueda estar haciendo mal. De hecho el codigo tal como esta a continuacion funciona, si lo cambio por las variables asignadas deja de hacerlo, me sale lo siguiente:

> index22.html:77 Uncaught ReferenceError: ls is not defined
>       at index22.html:77,

la cual corresponde a

```
var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(ls, lss, clientId);
```

al hacer por ejemplo un alert con las variables alert(js + " " + jss); me las muestra, pero no hace la conexión, arroja el error anterior. De antemano gracias.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Dashboard MQTT</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="Imagenes/iot.png">
  <script src='https://api.cloudmqtt.com/js/mqttws31.js' type='text/javascript'>
  </script>
  <!-- https://api.cloudmqtt.com/sso/js/mqttws31.js -->
</head>

<body>

  <header>

  </header>
  <br/>
  <h1>WEBSOCKET</h1><br />

  <div class="table">
    <form action="" method="post">
      <h2>Ingrese los datos</h2>
      <label for="host">Host:</label>
      <input type="text" id="host" name="host"><br/>
      <label for="puerto">Puerto:</label>
      <input type="text" id="puerto" name="puerto"><br/>
      <input type="submit" onclick="leerdatosformulario()" value="ENVIAR">
    </form>
  </div>
  <script>
    function leerdatosformulario() {
      ls = document.getElementById("host").value;
      lss = document.getElementById("puerto").value;
    }

    usuario = 'Prueba';
    contrasena = '123';
    puerto = 33848;
    host = 'm12.cloudmqtt.com';

    function onConnect() {
      // Once a connection has been made, make a subscription and send a message.
      console.log("Conexion realizada con el servidor");
      client.subscribe("#");
      console.log("Conectado como " + usuario + " a través del puerto 8083");
    }

    // called when the client loses its connection
    function onConnectionLost(responseObject) {
      if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
        console.log("onConnectionLost:", responseObject.errorMessage);
        setTimeout(function() {
          client.connect()
        }, 5000);
      }
    }

    // called when a message arrives
    function onMessageArrived(message) {

      var topico = document.getElementsByName("topico-pub")[0].value;
      if (message.destinationName == '/' + usuario + '/' + topico) { //acá coloco el topic
        document.getElementById("mensaje-pub").textContent = message.payloadString;
        console.log("Mensaje recibido:" + '/' + usuario + '/' + topico + " : " + message.payloadString);
      }
    }

    function onFailure(invocationContext, errorCode, errorMessage) {
      var errDiv = document.getElementById("error");
      errDiv.textContent = "Could not connect to WebSocket server, most likely you're behind a firewall that doesn't allow outgoing connections to port 33848";
      errDiv.style.display = "block";
    }

    var clientId = "ws" + Math.random();
    // Create a client instance
    var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(ls, lss, clientId);

    // set callback handlers
    client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
    client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;

    // connect the client
    client.connect({
      useSSL: true,
      userName: usuario,
      password: contrasena,
      onSuccess: onConnect,
      onFailure: onFailure
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Parece que el problema es que la conexión se hace al cargar la página, pero los valores que usas para la conexión no se leen hasta que no se pulsa el botón. Deberías reestructurar el código (p.e. mover la conexión a dentro de una función, y que sólo se llame cuando los valores estén rellenos). Pero no se puede ver exactamente porque el código que compartes no coincide con el código que te genera el error. Lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve].

Comment: ya lo volvi a editar de la forma en que me muestra el error, es la primera vez que publico en stackoverflow, de manera que tendré en cuenta las recomendaciones. Gracias

Comment: No te preocupes, todos publicamos por primera vez alguna vez, y la pregunta te ha quedado bien. El problema es el que te comentaba arriba, ahora mismo no puedo contestarte, pero en un rato, si nadie lo ha hecho, te pongo una explicación del problema y cómo resolverlo.

Comment: seria de gran ayuda. Gracias

Comment: Pero básicamente la solución es mover todo lo que hay después de la función `onFailure` (fuera de las funciones) y ponerlo al final de la función `leerdatosformulario()`. De ese modo las variables estarán instanciadas cuando se realice la conexión.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo en usuario y contraseña por que no tienes las variables asignadas, otra cosa la funcion donde capturas si esta devolviendo valores. prueba con un console.log(ls); a ver si esta capturando esa variable de tu codigo

Comment: Hola Alberto Julio, esta respuesta ha sido marcada como de muy baja calidad por la comunidad. Por favor, lee [answer] y edítala para añadir más información. Por ejemplo: ¿qué variables no tiene asignadas? ¿cómo o dónde debe hacer `console.log(variable)`? ¿Y para ver qué variable? Esta respuesta parece más un comentario que una respuesta.

Comment: @HAROLDLEONARDOHOYOSCARRILLO Debes editar tu pregunta para añadir esa información adicional. Además, deberías indicar en qué línea de código exacta te da ese error (¿cuál es la línea 74?) y compartir esa parte del código (si no se ha compartido ya). Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información y consejos.

Comment: `function leerdatosformulario(){
        ls = document.getElementById("host").value;
        lss = document.getElementById("puerto").value; 
       usuario = 'Prueba';
      contrasena = '123';
      puerto = lss;
      host = ls; }`            De esta manera no te funciona ?

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que la conexión se hace al cargar la página, pero los valores que usas para la conexión no se leen hasta que no se pulsa el botón (en la función `leerdatosformulario`). Deberías reestructurar el código (mover la conexión a dentro de una función y que sólo se llame cuando los valores estén rellenos).

Básicamente la solución es mover todo lo que hay después de la función `onFailure` (fuera de las funciones) y ponerlo al final de la función `leerdatosformulario()`. De ese modo las variables estarán instanciadas cuando se realice la conexión.

Este código te debería funcionar:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Dashboard MQTT</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="Imagenes/iot.png">
  <script src='https://api.cloudmqtt.com/js/mqttws31.js' type='text/javascript'>
  </script>
  <!-- https://api.cloudmqtt.com/sso/js/mqttws31.js -->
</head>

<body>

  <header>

  </header>
  <br/>
  <h1>WEBSOCKET</h1><br />

  <div class="table">
    <form action="" method="post">
      <h2>Ingrese los datos</h2>
      <label for="host">Host:</label>
      <input type="text" id="host" name="host"><br/>
      <label for="puerto">Puerto:</label>
      <input type="text" id="puerto" name="puerto"><br/>
      <input type="submit" onclick="leerdatosformulario()" value="ENVIAR">
    </form>
  </div>
  <script>
    usuario = 'Prueba';
    contrasena = '123';
    puerto = 33848;
    host = 'm12.cloudmqtt.com';

    function leerdatosformulario() {
      ls = document.getElementById("host").value;
      lss = document.getElementById("puerto").value;

      var clientId = "ws" + Math.random();
      // Create a client instance
      var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(ls, parseInt(lss), clientId);

      // set callback handlers
      client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
      client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;

      // connect the client
      client.connect({
        useSSL: true,
        userName: usuario,
        password: contrasena,
        onSuccess: onConnect,
        onFailure: onFailure
      });
    }

    function onConnect() {
      // Once a connection has been made, make a subscription and send a message.
      console.log("Conexion realizada con el servidor");
      client.subscribe("#");
      console.log("Conectado como " + usuario + " a través del puerto 8083");
    }

    // called when the client loses its connection
    function onConnectionLost(responseObject) {
      if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
        console.log("onConnectionLost:", responseObject.errorMessage);
        setTimeout(function() {
          client.connect()
        }, 5000);
      }
    }

    // called when a message arrives
    function onMessageArrived(message) {

      var topico = document.getElementsByName("topico-pub")[0].value;
      if (message.destinationName == '/' + usuario + '/' + topico) { //acá coloco el topic
        document.getElementById("mensaje-pub").textContent = message.payloadString;
        console.log("Mensaje recibido:" + '/' + usuario + '/' + topico + " : " + message.payloadString);
      }
    }

    function onFailure(invocationContext, errorCode, errorMessage) {
      var errDiv = document.getElementById("error");
      errDiv.textContent = "Could not connect to WebSocket server, most likely you're behind a firewall that doesn't allow outgoing connections to port 33848";
      errDiv.style.display = "block";
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: De hecho sigue sin funcionar, me muestra en consola un error Uncaught Error: Invalid Type String for Port, y al mirar también en consola me arroja los valores para host y puerto que se ingresaron en el formulario pero aun asi por el error que dije anteriormente no se conecta al servidor

Comment: @HAROLDLEONARDOHOYOSCARRILLO He cambiado el código un poco, poniendo `parseInt(lss)` y ya no sale el error que mencionas. Lo que hace es parsear la variable para que sea tratada como un entero en lugar de como una cadena de texto. Ahora da otro error diferente, pero ese se debe a que el ejemplo ejecutable que pongo aquí está en modo sandbox y no puede realizar algunas operaciones. Debes probar en tu lado, con el usuario y contraseña adecuadas.

Comment: Definitivamente no se que pueda ser, he estado mirando el codigo fuente de la página "CloudMqtt" y ellos también pasan el usuario, la contraseña el puerto y el host en el código, no se si ya sea el script de mqttws31.js, será hacer lo mismo mientras encuentro la manera